# Is "of" or "from" correct here?

Tags: grammar

He ran down the hall and entered his room just before two gunmen stepped out of/from the stairwell.

Is "of" or "from" or both correct here?

Comment: Yeah, both work, I don't see an issue with either.  I personally would have said "of" without thinking, maybe because it starts with a vowel and is easier to say?  Or because when I say this sentence fast I can shorten "of" to an "uh" sound, as in "stepped outta the stairwell".  You can't do that with "from".